# Route in Rails for json depends on where called from

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, json, routes, jbuilder

A file `maps.json` is created and is used in the following JavaScript

```
function findSelectedMap(mapID, cb) {
   $.getJSON('maps.json', function(json) { 
    json.forEach(function(entry) {
      if (entry.maps.id == mapID) {
        changeLayerTo = entry.maps.url;
        maxZoom = entry.maps.zoom;
      }
    });
    cb();
  });
};
```

It works fine when called from the top level `http://localhost:3000/overview` with `mapId` being

```
mapID = $("#select-overlay input[type='radio']:checked").val();
```

But when called from `http://localhost:3000/streets/45`, the error is `http://localhost:3000/streets/streets/maps.json 404 (Not Found)`. I tried `get 'streets/maps.json' => 'maps.json'` and similar in routes.Redondo Beach without success. I suppose I could force maps.json to be in `streets` and do a if exists (whatever the jS is), but that seems to cumbersome. Is there a way around this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can add the slash to the beginning of the endpoint to let browser know your URL starting from base URL

```
$.getJSON('/maps.json', function(json) {
  // rest of logic
})
```

Comment: Thank you. I knew it had to be simple. But still didn't think of that.